# How to interpret increasing node and listener count in Chrome timeline

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-management, google-analytics

I've been trying to identify why my web application is becoming significantly slower over time and have been doing some profiling in Chrome timeline. I may have narrowed down the problem to the Google Analytics JavaScript library.

I've created a [minimal reproduction of the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/wT0dlw?p=preview) which fires a tracking event every second (using the `ga` function).

In the timeline below you can see the node and listener count steadily increasing without being disposed of during the intermittent garbage collection.

To me this looks like a memory leak but I can't be sure if it is actually the expected behaviour.

[image]

Can anyone tell me if this is the expected behaviour and why new nodes and listeners and being created? Is there a way I can prevent this from happening or am I misusing the Google Analytics library?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about website performance and is not programing related.  May be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/